# How to work with checkboxes in Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm working with checkboxes in `Laravel` and  `Livewire`, I have a problem on editing record I can get to checked ids users were selected during record creation.

Here is my flow

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (isset($members)) @foreach ($members as $key=>$user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{++$key}}.</td>
            <td class="text-capitalize">{{$user->full_name ?? ''}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->title->name ?? ''}}</td>
            <td>{!!$user->current_status ?? ''!!}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-6 w-6" wire:model.debounce.50000ms="ids.{{$user->id}}" value="{{$user->id}}" id="ids.{{$user->id}}" @if($selectedUsers- />contains($user->id)) checked @endif></td>
        </tr>

        @endforeach @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
@if (isset($members)) {{ $members->links() }} @endif
```

How can I check these checkboxes based on ids stored in the database?

Comment: don't use the attribute value when you bind to property in livewire

Comment: What's the correct way to get it work @Prospero ?, I removed value attribute I can see checked attribute but nothing happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to make it work by initiating `public $selectedUsers = [];`

Then On my livewire component

```
<input  type="checkbox" class="form-control" wire:model.defer="selectedUsers" value="{{$user->id}}"  @if($selectedUsers->contains($user->id)) checked @endif>
```

On editing make sure you take ids that was stored during record creation from the database and assign them to `$this->selectedUsers`.

```
$this->selectedUsers = $this->production->users()->whereTitleId($this->request->title_id)->with('title:id,name')->pluck('id);
```

Everything should work fine, cheers

Answer (score 1):

First, I think that bind the element with the id property isn't a good idea. In your case, if the checks only is for the $user existence, then you don't need bind anything, just use the @if statement for that.

```
<input  type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-6 w-6" id="ids.{{$user->id}}" @if($selectedUsers->contains($user->id)) checked @endif>
```

Comment: I have applied that and I can see checboxes are checked so what will happen on saving these new checked boxes it means I have to apply ```wire:click``` ? @Prospero

Comment: be sure that @if statement returns the correct values, make dd($selectedUsers->contains($user->id))  in backend and see if that return true or false correctly, maybe instead $user->id must be just $user, depend of your collection type

Comment: I am comparing only user ids and its working but am just thinking on what to do when I need to save back to the database after checking new items.

Comment: use the wire:change...i'm going to update my answer

Comment: I was able to make it work buddy check my answer down there, thanks alot, you can edit it to be meaningful. @Prospero

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i retrieve the users in the `mount()` function, and associate then to the `$selectedUsers` array, setting the id as key and the values as string.

```
$userList = Users::select('id')->get();
foreach ($userList as $item){
    $this->selectedUsers[$item->id] = $item->id . '';
}
```

And in my component, i put this way:

`<input type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" wire:model.defer="selectedUsers.{{ $user->id }}" />{{ $user->name }}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).